# The number of people who connected all 6 zones in an event

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I've developed an app for event. In the event there are 6 different zones and attendees can connect each other from each of the zone from the app.

My sample db table data is in below :

[image]

I am trying to get all the people who are connected in all the 6 zones.

I am struggling to write the mysql query for this.

Can you advise any approach with sample query code?

Comment: This sounds like [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_.28.C3.B7.29) there's a question about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302581/mysql-relational-division

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks. Buy i'm trying to get all connections from the same table not from different table