# Extract tuples with specified common values in another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, r

I have a dataset that look like:

```
 Col1    Col2    
 1        ABC 
 2        DEF
 3        ABC 
 1        DEF
```

Expected output:

```
Col1     Col2    
 1        ABC 
 1        DEF
```

I want to extract only those IDSs from Col1 which have both values `ABC` and `DEF` in the column.

I tried the `self-join` in SQL but that did not give me the expected result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1
FROM db A, db B
WHERE A.ID <> B.ID
    AND A.Col2 = 'ABC'
    AND B.Col2 = 'DEF' 
GROUP BY A.Col1
```

Also, I tried to the same thing in R using the following code:

```
vc <- c("ABC", "DEF")
data1 <- db[db$Col2 %in% vc,]
```

Again, I did not get the desired output. Thanks for all the pointers in advance.

Comment: FYI, the operation you are looking for is called [relational division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Relational Division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302581/mysql-relational-division)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your current query corrected:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Col1
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
WHERE t1.Col2 = 'ABC' AND t2.Col2 = 'DEF';
```

### Demo

The join condition is that both `Col1` values are the *same*, the first `Col2` value is `ABC` and the second `Col2` value is `DEF`.

But, I would probably use the following canonical approach to this:

```
SELECT Col1
FROM yourTable
WHERE Col2 IN ('ABC', 'DEF')
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING MIN(Col2) <> MAX(Col2);
```

Answer (score 7):

In R, you could do

```r
library(dplyr) 
df %>% 
   group_by(Col1) %>% 
   filter(all(vc %in% Col2))

#   Col1 Col2 
#  <int> <fct>
#1     1 ABC  
#2     1 DEF
```

---

The Base R equivalent of that would be

```r
df[as.logical(with(df, ave(Col2, Col1, FUN = function(x) all(vc %in% x)))), ]

#  Col1 Col2
#1    1  ABC
#4    1  DEF
```

We select the groups which has all of `vc` in them.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, we can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(vc %in% Col2)], by = col1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery:

```
select * from tablename t 
where exists (select 1 from tablename t1 where t1.col1=t.col1 and col2 in ('ABC','DEF')
group by col1 having count(distinct col2)=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using group_concat

```
select t.Col1,t.col2
from t
join
(
select col1,group_concat(distinct col2 order by col2) gc
from t
group by col1 having gc = 'abc,def'
) s
on s.col1 = t.col1;

+------+------+
| Col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |
|    1 | DEF  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

But you do have to understand the order that col2 will be in