# R dplyr: filter common values by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to find common values between different groups ideally using dplyr and R.

From my dataset here:

```
  group   val
  <fct> <dbl>
1 a         1
2 a         2
3 a         3
4 b         3
5 b         4
6 b         5
7 c         1
8 c         3
```

the expected output is

```
group   val
<fct> <dbl>
1 a         3
2 b         3
3 c         3
```

as only number 3 occurs in all groups.

This code seems not working:

```
# Filter the data 

dd %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(all(val))           # does not work
```

Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620832/extract-tuples-with-specified-common-values-in-another-column-in-sql) solves similar issue but have a defined vector of shared values. What if I do not know which ones are shared?

Dummy example:

```
# Reproducible example: filter all id by group
group = c("a", "a", "a",
          "b", "b", "b",
          "c", "c")
val = c(1,2,3,
        3,4,5,
        1,3)

dd <- data.frame(group,
                 val)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group_by` isolates each group, so we can't very well `group_by(group)` and compare between between groups. Instead, we can `group_by(val)` and see which ones have all the groups:

```
dd %>%
  group_by(val) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(group) == n_distinct(dd$group))
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
# # Groups:   val [1]
#   group   val
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 a         3
# 2 b         3
# 3 c         3
```

This is one of the rare cases where we want to use `data$column` in a `dplyr` verb - `n_distinct(dd$group)` refers explicitly to the ungrouped original data to get the total number of groups. (It could also be pre-computed.) Whereas `n_distinct(group)` is using the grouped data piped in to `filter`, thus it gives the number of distinct groups for each value (because we `group_by(val)`).

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` approach can be:

```
#Code
newd <- dd[dd$val %in% Reduce(intersect, split(dd$val, dd$group)),]
```

Output:

```
  group val
3     a   3
4     b   3
8     c   3
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar option in `data.table` as that of @GregorThomas solution is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[dd[, .I[uniqueN(group) == uniqueN(dd$group)], val]$V1]
```